# Why Settings app doesnot list app that is integrated within another app?

Tags: iphone, ios, settings.bundle

I have a created an app, consider its app name as 'X', has integrated another app with app name 'Y'. App 'Y' is like a framework with only .h and .m files. I created a settings bundle for the app 'X', this successfully is listed in Settings app. But when I add another Settings bundle to the app that is integrated, that is app 'Y', it is not listed in Settings app, When i run 'X', that is the main app that has the 'Y' app integrated.

Can i do this? Please let me know if there is better way do achieve this..

Please help. I don't know how to proceed.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean that you've "integrated another app"?  From your description, it doesn't sound like Y is an app at all.

Comment: If i add settings bundle to 'Y' will it be listed in Settings app?

Comment: It would help to know what Y is.

Comment: Its a framework. I have realized that my approach is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think an app can have multiple Settings bundles.
I suppose it is possible to integrate one Settings bundle in another though.

[This iOS framework](https://github.com/jverkoey/iOS-Framework) writeup has a good explanation of what your options are to add projects in other projects, coping with resource bundles, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Every app is only allowed on settings bundle, which needs to be in the root of your Application bundle. 
Therefor what you are trying to achieve is not possible, you should include the settingas for your library in you apps settings.

Comment: can you please elaborate on how to proceed.?

Comment: No, I can not. My answer is really clear, You should just add the same settings from the library to you apps settings. There is no other way.